# Bump + OpenStreetMap Error

Tags: iphone, ld, openstreetmap, fmdb, bump

I have problem with use OpenStreetMap lib and Bump lib.

I obtained critical error -

```
ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_FMDatabase.databasePath in /Users/ 
alex/APP/BumpAPI/libBumpAPI.a(FMDatabase.o) and /Users/alex/APP/ 
CloudMade/libs/route-me/libMapView.a(FMDatabase.o) for architecture 
armv6 

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status 
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm- 
gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I find solve for this problem.

I find sources of RoutMe library, that includes in CloudMade library. And change name of class "FMDatabase" to "_FMDatabase". Next, rebuild libMapView.

But, this problem exist with other libraries (non open-source) in other projects.